# mod_rewrite suddenly not working, ONLY for incoming POST requests from Foursquare API

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have an endpoint on my website where I receive push notifications from the FourSquare API.  The endpoint is:

```
https://www.example.com/auth/foursquare/
```

On the server itself, the source file is:

```
/home/myusername/public_html/www.example.com/auth/foursquare/index.php
```

Ordinarily, the site's files would be in:

```
/home/myusername/public_html/
```

But I'm using mod_rewrite to instead place them in a subdirectory of the usual webroot:

```
/home/myusername/public_html/www.example.com/
```

These are the mod_rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www.example.com/$1 [L]
```

So far so good.  Everything works like this, and has worked without issue for many years.  Until suddenly, a couple months ago, FourSquare pushes stopped coming through.  Investigation of the server error logs showed that for some reason it's now trying to serve files from the original (non-rewritten) path:

```
2019-12-30 00:26:31.383141 [INFO] [34.231.230.177:15669] File not found [/home/myusername/public_html/auth/foursquare/]
2019-12-30 00:26:31.383256 [INFO] [34.231.230.177:15669] File not found [/home/myusername/public_html/404.shtml]
```

What's really strange is that this ONLY happens when the incoming request comes from the foursquare API itself:

- I can *VISIT* https://www.example.com/auth/foursquare/ in a browser, and it serves the correct file.
- I can POST to https://www.example.com/auth/foursquare/ with Postman or Insomnia or any other API test tool, and it serves the correct file.  Even if I replicate the headers & POST data from FourSquare precisely (which I determined by changing the FourSquare app to push to a hookbin endpoint, so I can examine the exact data they're sending).

The only common denominator I can think of is the source IP; when the POST comes from FourSquare's IP, mod_rewrite is not serving the expected file from the subdirectory - but from all other IPs it does.  Though obviously I don't have any IP-specific rules that would cause this, so that doesn't really make sense.

Because no code or htaccess rules have been changed on my end in a very long time (i.e. since well before this spontaneously started happening), it stands to reason that my (shared) webhost must have changed some server config that broke it.  But I've exchanged more than 20 messages with them where they just keep coming back to "we don't know why this is happening, just make a symlink from the original path and it will work."  It's true, making a symlink from /home/myusername/public_html/auth/ to /home/myusername/public_html/www.example.com/auth/ works.  However, that really doesn't explain why it suddenly broke, and IMO blind band-aid solutions are seldom a good idea.  What if whatever broke this has also affected something else, that I just haven't had the luck to notice yet?  I'd like to understand exactly what's going on, why it spontaneously stopped working, and how to *properly* fix it.  Sadly, it seems pretty clear that the webhost - which seems like the most likely culprit - is going to be of no help.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: "These are the mod_rewrite rules:" - by themselves, those directives would result in a rewrite loop, so you must either have other directives (in the same file) or additional `.htaccess` files (in subdirectories) that prevent this? "server error logs show..." - What about the _access logs_? Probably not the cause of the problem, but strictly speaking, you should be rewriting directly to the file that handles the request (ie. `index.php`). By rewriting to the _directory_ you are also dependent on mod_dir issuing an internal subrequest for the directory index.

Comment: Are you able to confirm whether it is just mod_rewrite that is somehow being bypassed, or the entire `.htaccess` file? mod_security (if enabled) can sometimes trigger seemingly bizarre responses - do you have any control over this on your server?

Comment: Thanks for the replies @MrWhite :)  re: you must either have other directives (in the same file) or additional .htaccess files (in subdirectories) that prevent this? --- Nope, that's it; while debugging this, I trimmed down /home/myusername/public_html/.htaccess to just those 2 lines and nothing else.  There is /home/myusername/public_html/www.example.com/.htaccess, but during testing I also trimmed it down to just one line: "RewriteEngine on".   Behavior is as described with these fully trimmed down htaccess.

Comment: re: What about the access logs? :::: When I visit manually in a browser (which works, aka executes the correct index.php), access logs show: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [03/Jan/2020:03:54:38 -0500] "GET /auth/foursquare/ HTTP/2" 200 13 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0" :::: When I push from FourSquare (which doesn't work), access logs show: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [03/Jan/2020:03:54:44 -0500] "POST /auth/foursquare/ HTTP/1.1" 404 618 "-" "FoursquarePush/1.0"

Comment: re: but strictly speaking, you should be rewriting directly to the file that handles the request (ie. index.php). By rewriting to the directory you are also dependent on mod_dir issuing an internal subrequest for the directory index :::: Sure, but that couldn't be what's going on here, right?  Because per the error logs, it's not even looking in the right subdirectory (per the htaccess rewrites).  If it were i.e. looking in the right subdirectory but just not index.php, I'd think that would be reflected differently in the error logs.

Comment: Re: mod_security (if enabled) can sometimes trigger seemingly bizarre responses - do you have any control over this on your server? :::: Not not directly, but I had the webhost temporarily disable mod_security, & the behavior was the same.

Comment: Re: Are you able to confirm whether it is just mod_rewrite that is somehow being bypassed, or the entire .htaccess file? :::: Not sure how I might test that...?

Comment: "Nope, that's it" - The `RewriteEngine` directive in the `/www.example.com/.htaccess` file is what prevents a rewrite loop here (this prevents the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file from being called again after the first rewrite - since mod_rewrite is not inherited by default). I didn't think mod_dir would be the problem here (since it works when making a GET request), but it's demonstrating that this process is dependent on other factors... in this case, the value of the `DirectoryIndex` directive (which could theoretically be set conditionally in the server config).

Comment: "per the error logs, it's not even looking in the right subdirectory" - well, I wasn't sure (just looking at the error logs)... Is the "requested URL" being logged here (as in the access log) or the internally rewritten URL (if different)? I'm not sure. 404 _responses_ are not "normally" logged in the error log, as they aren't strictly _errors_.

Comment: I can't imagine that it would just be mod_rewrite that is bypassed. However, I'm struggling with the idea that `.htaccess` would be bypassed, unless perhaps there was some other security module that was blocking the request. But you seem to have ruled that out, and I wouldn't have expected a 404 in this case (perhaps a 406 or even 500 response). I would try... **1.** temporarily change your rewrite into an external redirect, ie. just add the `R` flag (`[R,L]`) to the `RewriteRule`. Do you now see a 302 response in your access log when you "push from FourSquare"?

Comment: If you see a 302 response then the mod_rewrite directives are not being "bypassed", they would seem to be failing for some other reason. However, if you don't see a 302 response then... **2.** Try adding a mod_alias `Redirect` instead (comment out the mod_rewrite directives). eg. `Redirect /auth/foursquare/ /www.example.com/auth/foursquare/` (this obviously does not check the hostname, as the mod_rewrite directives did) - do you now see a 302 response in the access log for the "push from FourSquare" request?

Comment: >>Is the "requested URL" being logged here (as in the access log) or the internally rewritten URL (if different)? I'm not sure. ////

I was just referring to the log messages in the OP, where it shows File Not Found & just that it's looking in the non-rewritten local server path (i.e. search above for text: "2019-12-30 00:26:31.383141")

Comment: >>temporarily change your rewrite into an external redirect, ie. just add the R flag ([R,L]) to the RewriteRule. Do you now see a 302 response in your access log when you "push from FourSquare"? //// 

Error logs still show the same 404s, and access log still shows: 34.231.230.177 - - [06/Jan/2020:05:56:18 -0500] "POST /auth/foursquare/ HTTP/1.1" 404 618 "-" "FoursquarePush/1.0"

Comment: >>Try adding a mod_alias Redirect instead //// 

Yup, now I see a 302: 34.231.230.177 - - [06/Jan/2020:05:59:48 -0500] "POST /auth/foursquare/ HTTP/1.1" 302 593 "-" "FoursquarePush/1.0".  Note: The FourSquare push console still shows it was an error and my receiving script didn't get the POST data, so I guess their 'client' doesn't actually follow the redirect - but the server logs do show 302 rather than 404.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the host being requested is still `example.com` or `www.example.com` (exactly, and not FQ with a trailing dot)? Do you need to check the hostname (do you host multiple domains on this account)? I would certainly try removing the mod_rewrite condition that checks the hostname whilst testing.

Comment: >>Have you confirmed that the host being requested is still example.com or www.example.com (exactly, and not FQ with a trailing dot)? /// Sorry, I'm not really clear on what I should be checking (or how)...could you explain? FQ with a trailing dot...?

Comment: >>Do you need to check the hostname (do you host multiple domains on this account)? /// Yeah, I host a bunch of domains.  That's actually the rationale for rewriting this domain into a subfolder public_html/www.example.com - to keep each domain in its own separate subfolder, i.e. public_html/www.example2.com/, public_html/www.anotherexample.com/, etc (rather than the 'main' domain being in the webroot public_html/, and all the other domains being mixed in - this way, they're all clean & separate).

Comment: >>I would certainly try removing the mod_rewrite condition that checks the hostname whilst testing.  /// So just to clarify: you mean remove the RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ [NC], correct?  - That...actually did make the push work!!!  Super weird!  What does that tell us though - and why would the behavior suddenly have changed a few months ago, where that rule always worked in the past? (And of course...removing that isn't an actual solution, because it would break all the other domains hosted on the account).  Steps in the right direction though!! :)

Comment: "That...actually did make the push work!!! Super weird!" - Interesting! That would seem to suggest that the requested hostname is not what you are expecting (or the HTTP_HOST var is being set incorrectly by your server - but that is less likely). The FQDN (fully qualified domain name) ends in a dot eg. `example.com.` - this would normally still reach your server, but your condition would fail. You can test what the HTTP_HOST var is set to by doing something like: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www.example.com/$1?reqhost=%{HTTP_HOST} [L]` and check the value of the `reqhost` URL param in your code.

Comment: Reqhost was set to: "www.example.com:443".....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Reqhost was set to: "www.example.com:443"

That would certainly seem to be the cause of the problem. Although *why* the port (the request is being sent on) is now present in the `Host` header is another matter. `443` is the default port for HTTPS. However, since it is the *default* port, it does not *need* to be be present in the `Host` header. You would only *need* the port specified if you were serving content from non-standard ports.

It's possible that FourSquare has started sneakily including the port number as part of the request (assuming this has not been mistakenly set within your config at FourSquare?) - although this would arguably be incorrect (although not strictly a violation of the [spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23)) as it would restrict your server to using the default ports (you should be able to use whatever port you want).

The other possibility is that you have a (new) front-end proxy that is perhaps appending the port number to the forwarded request to your application server. But this is unlikely as it would presumably affect all requests and from your tests, this is not the case.

The "fix" would seem to be to allow for the port number in the request (assuming only port 443 and not port 80 - plain HTTP).

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com(:443)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /www.example.com/$1 [L]
```

`(:443)?` makes the port number *optional* in the `Host` header (should the situation reverse itself).

Don't forget to escape literal dots in the regex (*CondPattern*).

`^(.*)$` can be simplified to `(.*)` since regex is greedy by default.

Comment: Amazing - thanks so much for helping me get to the bottom of this!  So it looks like it most likely was FourSquare that screwed things up after all (& not my webhost).  What a weird change for them to suddenly/silently make.